# Insert from sub queries

Tags: mysql, magento

I'm trying to insert based on the results of a sub query, but I keep getting the same error:

```
Operand should contain 1 column(s)
```

Here's the query:

```
INSERT INTO customer_entity_int

(attribute_id, entity_type_id, entity_id, `value`)

VALUES (14, (
    SELECT entity_type_id, entity_id, `value`
    FROM customer_entity_int
    WHERE attribute_id = 13
    AND entity_id NOT
    IN (
        SELECT entity_id
        FROM customer_entity_int
        WHERE attribute_id = 14
    )
))
```

How can I select more than one column for my insert?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will want to use `INSERT INTO...SELECT FROM` instead of the `INSERT INTO..VALUES`:

```
INSERT INTO customer_entity_int (attribute_id, entity_type_id, entity_id, `value`)
SELECT 14, entity_type_id, entity_id, `value`
FROM customer_entity_int
WHERE attribute_id = 13
  AND entity_id NOT IN (SELECT entity_id
                        FROM customer_entity_int
                        WHERE attribute_id = 14)
```

You can include a static value in your `SELECT` list for your `attribute_id`

Comment: Perfect, this worked a treat, I'll accept as soon as it lets me

Answer (score 2):

Try dis:

```
INSERT INTO customer_entity_int

(attribute_id, entity_type_id, entity_id, `value`)

    SELECT 14, entity_type_id, entity_id, `value`
    FROM customer_entity_int
    WHERE attribute_id = 13
    AND entity_id NOT
    IN (
        SELECT entity_id
        FROM customer_entity_int
        WHERE attribute_id = 14
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following code.....

```
INSERT INTO customer_entity_int
(attribute_id, entity_type_id, entity_id, `value`)
SELECT 14, entity_type_id, entity_id, `value`
FROM customer_entity_int
WHERE attribute_id = 13
AND entity_id NOT
IN (
    SELECT entity_id
    FROM customer_entity_int
    WHERE attribute_id = 14
   )
```